# partial matching result in array removal

Tags: elasticsearch

Used the following query to search books with name 'new java ' or ' java new'

```
"bool":{  
             "must":[  
                  {  
                     "term":{  
                        "title":{
              "value":"new"
             }
                     }
                  },
                  {  
                     "term":{  
                        "title":{
              "value":"java"
             }
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
```

It is giving the value exactly but showing duplicate records also what i mean is, It should not return  the following as it has ' new' and 'java' which is in different index but this result also displaying

```
{  
   "_index":"book-lists",
   "_type":"book-list",
   "_id":"AVBRSvHIXb7carZwcePS",
   "_version":1,
   "_score":1,
   "_source":{  
      "title":"Technology",
      "books":[  
         {  
            "title":"Java",
            "isRead":true,
            "summary":"lorem ipsum",
            "rating":3.5
         },
     {  
            "title":"java jsp",
            "isRead":true,
            "summary":"lorem ipsum",
            "rating":3.5
         },
    {  
            "title":"new servlet",
            "isRead":true,
            "summary":"lorem ipsum",
            "rating":3.5
         }
      ],
      "numberViews":0,
      "idOwner":"17xxxxxxxxxxxx45"
   }
}
```

Is it possible to avoid the match which is in different index of array.

Comment: If it's only the index problem, why not search only the index you need?

Comment: I didn't mean ES index. meant books array index